# Create new columns depending on the columns in a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have code in the this following example.

```
    legacy_id phone_type phone_number
         1        f      1234567890
         1        b      1233854100
         1        f      4110256565
         2        f      0707070770
         2        b      7895120044
```

I want the data to end up like the following.

```
    legacy_id  f_phone_number_1 b_phone_number_1 f_phone_number_2
         1      1234567890        1233854100        4110256565
         2      0707070770        7895120044
```

My initial approach works but I was hoping there is a more efficient what of doing this.

```
    Select fill.legacy_id, max(fill.f_phone_number_1),max(fill.b_phone_number_1),max(fill.f_phone_number_2)
    from
    (
      Select
           a.legacy_id as legacy_id, a.phone_type as phone_type,
           case
               when a.phone_type = 'F' then a.phone_number and 
               dense_rank() over (partition by a.legacy_id, a.phone_type order by a.legacy_id, a.phone_type, a.phone_number) = 1
               else null
           end as f_phone_number_1,
           case
               when a.phone_type = 'F' then a.phone_number and
               dense_rank() over (partition by a.legacy_id, a.phone_type order by a.legacy_id, a.phone_type, a.phone_number) = 2
               else null
           end as f_phone_number_2,
           case
               when a.phone_type = 'b' then a.phone_number and
               dense_rank() over (partition by a.legacy_id, a.phone_type order by a.legacy_id, a.phone_type, a.phone_number) = 1
               else null
           end as b_phone_number_1
      from table a
      group by a.legacy_id, a.phone_type, a.phone_number
    ) fill
    group by fill.legacy_id
```

Is there a more efficient way of approaching this?

Comment: looks like you should be able to pivot using dynamic sql. It'd be less code, and would be scalable, but performance would really depend.

Comment: Cannot be scalable because this will select will be used to insert into a table. Although I like the pivot idea.

Comment: You may want to move this to codereview.stackexchange.com as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to go dynamic, a conditional aggregation should do the trick

```
Declare @YourTable table (legacy_id int,phone_type varchar(25),phone_number varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'f','1234567890'),
(1,'b','1233854100'),
(1,'f','4110256565'),
(2,'f','0707070770'),
(2,'b','7895120044')

Select legacy_id
      ,f_phone_number_1 = max(case when phone_type='f' and RowNr=1 Then phone_number else '' end)
      ,b_phone_number_1 = max(case when phone_type='b' and RowNr=1 Then phone_number else '' end)
      ,f_phone_number_2 = max(case when phone_type='f' and RowNr=2 Then phone_number else '' end)
      ,b_phone_number_2 = max(case when phone_type='b' and RowNr=2 Then phone_number else '' end)
 From (
        Select *
              ,RowNr=Row_Number() over (Partition By legacy_id,phone_type Order By (Select NULL) ) 
         From  @YourTable 
      ) A
 Group By legacy_id
```

Returns

```
legacy_id   f_phone_number_1    b_phone_number_1    f_phone_number_2    b_phone_number_2
1           4110256565          1233854100          1234567890  
2           0707070770          7895120044
```

Comment: Is the performance better using row_number() vs dense_rank()? As of right now your script looks similar to mine.

Comment: @LetUsSeng Only doing 1 pass here in the sub-query.   Couldn't hurt to try.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a shot.

Comment: I gave it a shot and I like it. It is a cleaner than what I came up with. Thanks.

Comment: @LetUsSeng Happy to help,  Just curious, why did you de-select as answer?

Comment: I think I did by mistake. My bad.

Comment: @LetUsSeng No worries.  Cheers